# AngularJS : get translate key in app.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

In my application, I use the AngularJS module Pascal Precht (translate module). I come to you because I can not get in my method `myApp.Run` of `app.js` a translation key. 
I can do in a controller or a view. But impossible to get it at the initialization of the project. It shows me the key, not correspondence.

Do you have a solution?

Here is my code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives', 'pascalprecht.translate']);

// Declare routeProvider
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl:'partials/connectView.html', controller:'ConnectController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/homeView', {templateUrl:'partials/homeView.html', controller:'HomeController'});
}]);

// Declare translateProvider
myApp.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {        
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'res/localization/lang-',
        suffix: '.json'
    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('fr_FR');
    //$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');
}]);

// Declare Global variables
myApp.run(['$rootScope', '$filter', function($rootScope, $filter) {
    $rootScope.list = false;
    etc....

    //I'm trying to get translate Key but it doesn't work
    console.log($filter('translate')('MY_KEY'));
}]);
```

My AngularJS version is 1.2.16 (last stable version). Thx

Comment: How about a fiddle demonstrating the issue ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try injecting the `$translate` service in `app.run()`.

#### angular-translate version 1.1.1 and below

```
myApp.run(['$rootScope', '$translate', '$log', function ($rootScope, $translate, $log) {
    $log.debug($translate('MY_KEY'));
}]);
```

I'd also suggest you to upgrade to the latest version of Pascal Precht's [**angular-translate**](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate). There are some [**changes**](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) in the [**new version**](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate).

#### angular-translate version 2.0.0 and above

```
myApp.run(['$rootScope', '$translate', '$log', function ($rootScope, $translate, $log) {
    // translate via promises (recommended way)
    $translate(['MY_KEY', 'MY_OTHER_KEY'])
            .then(function (translation) {
                $log.debug(translation.MY_KEY);
            });
    // translate instantly from the internal state of loaded translation
    $log.debug($translate.instant('MY_KEY'));
}]);
```

See this helpful [**migration guide**](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/21_migration-guide).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you inject the $translate service in the run section 
and then call it instead of using the filter?!

```
console.log($translate('MY_KEY'));
```

Comment: I tried and since I put the v 1.2.16 of AngularJS `$translate ('my_key')` no longer works. The result is `console.log($translate ('my_key')) = {};` 
While `console.log($filter('translate')('my_key')) = my_key` (the result is the key not the value).

Comment: Be careful as the $translate - return value is a promise which must be taken care of beginning with AngularJS 2.0 :-)

Comment: I too get a {} instead of the translation for the key. I inject the $translate service in the run section as well. I wonder what sort of care I need to take for that promise. I'm now running on AngularJs 1.2.24.

Comment: Got it now. $translate('DATEPICKER_CURRENT')).then(function(value) { datepickerPopupConfig.currentText = value; });

Answer (score 0):

Well, Apparently I can't comment because of reputation issue, we came across something that might be what you are experiencing - since the locale file is downloaded only in the config part of angular, it might not be available (yet) when you call the translate.

We solved this by adding all the locale files upfront (we don't have many and they are small) and in the initialization we just choose the correct one, that way we avoid the problem.

(again this should probably be more of a comment then an answer, but I can't comment...)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution for your issue, but if you try the following code in your 'run', you  will get an idea, why the translation is not available at the initializing state.

```
myApp.run(['$rootScope', '$filter','$timeout', function($rootScope, $filter,$timeout) {
    $timeout(function(){
      alert($filter('translate')('MY_KEY'));
    },5000)
}]);
```

Problem here is, by the time the translation is being loaded the 'run' will be executed. So it cannot be assured that you will get the translation loaded at that time.